# Error stating: 1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. Try adding the missing arguments

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to navigate from welcomepage to screen tab but unable to do so because of the above error.

**Part of welcome screen.dart**

```
class WelcomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/welcome-screen';
  const WelcomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Opacity(
                opacity: 0.3,
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/of_main_bg.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
                ),
                ),
                
                  ThemeButton(
                    label: "Get Started!",
                    labelColor: AppColors.MAIN_COLOR,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    highlight: AppColors.MAIN_COLOR.withOpacity(0.5),
                    borderColor: AppColors.MAIN_COLOR,
                    borderWidth: 4,
                    onPressed: ()  {Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return TabsScreen(**ERROR**#What should I write here);
              },
            ),
```

**Routes in main.dart**

```
initialRoute: '/', // default is '/'
  routes: {
    '/': (ctx) => WelcomePage(),
    CategoryMealsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CategoryMealsScreen(_availableMeals),
    MealDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => MealDetailScreen(_toggleFavorite, _isMealFavorite),
    FiltersScreen.routeName: (ctx) => FiltersScreen(_filters, _setFilters),
    TabsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => TabsScreen(_favoriteMeals),
    WelcomePage.routeName: (ctx) => WelcomePage(),
  },
```

**class code in tabscreen.dart**

```
 class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/tabs-screen';
  final List<Meal> favoriteMeals;

  TabsScreen(this.favoriteMeals);
```

How should i navigate from welcomepage to tabs_screen page?In order to navigate for the same what should I write in that **ERROR** place in welcome_screen.dart.
If there's another method for navigation please do tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use named routes.

From https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

> Note: Named routes are no longer recommended for most applications. For more information, see [Limitations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#limitations) in the [navigation overview](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation#limitations) page.

Comment: This helped "Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/tabs-screen');" .Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Your `TabsScreen` constructor is taking positional argument. You can pass empty list(`[]`) there. But making name constructor with nullable data seems better to me.

```dart
class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/tabs-screen';
  final List<Meal>? favoriteMeals;

  TabsScreen({ this.favoriteMeals});
```

Now it is optional, and you can pass list like `TabsScreen(favoriteMeals: yourData)` and skip when you don't want to pass `TabsScreen()`.

More about [using-constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)

Comment: Made constructor with nullable data but received an error stating : This requires the 'non-nullable' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.12.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.d

Comment: Seems like you aren't using null-safety. you can update the sdk from `pubspec.yaml` it can be like `environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'`